# Web Services in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, web-services

Could anyone explain to me how I would do this scenario as a web service method (I gave myself this exercise for learning purposes).

A list of things and their prices; `book` `0.50`, `notepad` `1.20`. Then a way for a user to type an amount, so if they type in 1 in textbox, if they type in 2 and select notepad, the amount is 2.40.

Do I need two Web Methods for this? What is the best way to store the things? I have attempted this but I get the errors that I don't have overload methods:

```
[WebMethod]
public ThingsPrices[] GetThings(string thing, decimal price)
{
    List<ThingsPrices> things = new List<ThingsPrices>();
    things.Add(new  ("book", 0.50);
    things.Add("notepad", 1.20); //No overload for method Add??
    return things.ToArray(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code for `ThingsPrices`?

Comment: Can we see your definition of `ThingsPrices`? You do have syntax issues, but without the definition, we can't reliably show you what it should be corrected to.

Comment: The reason you're getting errors concerning the constructors is because you're trying to use List.Add() with a string and a number. The method only accepts an object. What you're probably trying to do is something like this: `things.Add(new ThingsPrices("notepad", 1.20));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the collection initializer for your scenario:

```
public class ThingsPrices
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }

public ThingsPrices[] GetThings()
        {

            var things = new List<ThingsPrices>()
            {
                new ThingsPrices
                {
                    ItemName = "book",
                    Price = 0.5
                },
                new ThingsPrices
                {
                    ItemName = "notepad",
                    Price = 1.2
                }
            };

            return things.ToArray();
        }
```

Read more about this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx

Here is the total price calculation:

```
public class Amount
    {
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public ThingsPrices ItemType { get; set; }        
    }    

    public static List<Amount> InputItems = new List<Amount>();

    public class AmmountCalculator
    {       
        public double GetTotalAmmount()
        {
            return InputItems.Sum(i => i.ItemType.Price*i.Quantity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, what is the difference with laying out the list this way as opposed to the way i did it (even if it had errors haha)?

Comment: The collection initializers are good to use when you know the items of your collection from the beginning. The syntax is very clear, and the advantage is a more readable code.

Comment: I've never heard of collection initializers until now! I will read up on them now! also, how could I test the web service, previously, when I used existing web services input boxes would let you test the web service before deploying it, is there a way to do it with this? At the moment it shows the invoke button and then displays the XML but no textboxes

Comment: The default test page should appear if you are running your service on your local machine. But if your method does not have any arguments, you can simply test the method typing in the browser: `http://yourservice.asmx/GetThings`

Comment: When I run it on my local machine I get the web service page with the method GetThings and I click it, then I am presented with just an invoke button and nothing else. Am I supposed to add other methods for it display test textboxes? (sorry too many questions)

Comment: Here is a possible explanation: [link](http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/progdotnetws_2/index1.html?page=4) _Because our web method takes no arguments, the page need provide only a button for invocation. If our method had a different signature--for example, if it reads a string of text--the .aspx help page would also provide a text box to capture this string and pass it, using HTTP GET, to the web method when the form was submitted. This text box method works fine for simple data type arguments, but if the web method were to require an object, this approach would not work._

Comment: What does `arguments` mean? Is it bad that it doesn't take any arguments? I haven't deployed it with an asp.net web application yet, but to get the Things in a dropdown, would I have to use a for loop?

Comment: For your WebMethod `GetThings(string thing, decimal price)`, the arguments are `thing` and `price`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So would I put that in `public ThingsPrices[] GetThings(string thing, decimal price)` or would I need to create a separate a separate method? Is it best to put price as decimal or double?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different questions in your code so I'm not really clear what you try to achieve. First lets fix the code and then we can tackle the rest of the problems. Your code had some errors. The below should run fine:

```
[WebMethod]
public IEnumerable<ThingsPrice> GetThings(string thing, decimal price)
{
    List<ThingsPrices> things = new List<ThingsPrices>();
    things.Add(new ThingsPrice {"book", 0.50});
    things.Add(new ThingsPrice {"notepad", 1.20}); 
    return things; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got over excited and had so many ideas. Could you explain to me what `IEnumberable` is? Also, would it best to store the price as a decimal or a double?

Comment: Right now you are not storing it anywhere and the type you chose depends on your precision requirements. You can read up on `IEnumerable` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx. The TL;DR is that it's an abstraction around your collections so you can leave the concrete materialisation to the consumer. The can convert the IEnumerable to a List or an Array based on their needs

Comment: Hi, Chris, could you possibly tell me why a web service would not show textboxes to test the methods?

Comment: There are a lot of plugins and tools that allow you to test webservices. I would suggest you start with Fiddler and take it from there. It's a free download and well worth the investment in time as it's a handy tool.